# How do i parallelize julia code without changing the eventual output?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm new with parallel computing and managed to change my code in such a way that it runs faster than my non parallel code, however my results slightly differ. I tried using the @sync, @async, @threads, and @distributed macro's but none of them seem to keep the outcome correct.

The goal is finding the shortest path through a maze and while running the code non parallel works fine it seems that running the code in parallel does not finish all iterations of the search algorithm and in turn only gives the shortest path through the maze found by one of the threads/workers.

It mainly works by starting at a the entrance, iterating over all possible points it can travel to towards the exit, it then selects the point it reached the quickest and repeats those steps until the exit is reached. It does this using two non-nested for loops but when i increase the execution speed using macros like @async or @distributed it never finds the shortest path.

Is there a way to do this concurrently or parallel while still getting the same result at the end?

**Edit:**

I added an example of a function that has the same problem. How would you be able to get the same z value in the end while speeding things up with parallelization?

```
    a = rand(1, 2, 15)
    function stufftodo(a)                           
        z = 0
        y = rand(size(a)[1], size(a)[2]) .* 1000
        for i in 1:size(a)[3]
            x = a[:, :, i]
            sleep(0.05)
            if sum(y)>sum(x)
                y=x
            end
        end
        z = minimum(y)
    end
```

Comment: The answer is yes. Perhaps if you can show a MWE, someone can provide some help.

Comment: How do you parallelize your code? I would like to see how you do it. It might be that  you are missing more than one point. The parallel computing macros julia has are not full-magic. There are still things you should consider before parallelization (*coherence* and copy/access issues). `sleep(0.05)` is the bottleneck here. You use `sum(y)` each time, although you already have it from previous iteration. Note that I have parallelized the code, and it gives speed-up although not that significant since each element is accessed only once, which makes the problem almost all about RAM speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, any questions welcome:

Let us define the data for replicability of this example:

```
using Random
Random.seed!(0)
a = rand(1, 2, 15)
```

We start by measuring the timing of the original function. Since the first time Julia runs `@time` it compiles the code we measure twice (only the second measurement is valid):

```
julia> @time stufftodo(a)
  1.017913 seconds (654.90 k allocations: 33.067 MiB, 0.81% gc time)
0.042301665932029664

julia> @time stufftodo(a)
  0.772471 seconds (538 allocations: 69.813 KiB)
0.042301665932029664
```

Now let us go distributed:

```
using Distributed
nworkers()<4 && addprocs(4)

@everywhere function stufftodo2(a)
    y = rand(size(a)[1], size(a)[2]) .* 1000
    aggfunc = (x,y) -> sum(y)>sum(x) ? x : y
    y = @distributed (aggfunc) for i in 1:size(a)[3]
        sleep(0.05)
        a[:, :, i]
    end
    minimum(y)
end
```

Now we can measure the time of the distributed function (again only the second measurement is valid):

```
julia> @time stufftodo2(a)
  2.819767 seconds (2.46 M allocations: 124.442 MiB, 1.53% gc time)
0.042301665932029664

julia> @time stufftodo2(a)
  0.206596 seconds (447 allocations: 44.609 KiB)
0.042301665932029664
```

Comment: You are welcome. I just noted that `stufftodo2` does not require `@everywhere` in front of it - it is enough to define it on the master process.